# EC2 PHP API - describeInstances never returning specified instance ID

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to return the status of one specific instance, of which I have the ID. No matter what I do, the API call below returns all instances, not just one...what looks wrong? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_describeInstances

```
    $result = $ec2Client->describeInstances(array(
        'InstanceIds' => array($server_id);
        //tried all variations of array of 1 string, plus 'InstanceId' with just string
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a more general PHP misunderstanding by me, but with this:

```
$strArr = array(); $strArr[0] = $server_id;
```

It worked.

With any of the following

```
$strArr = array(); $strArr[] = $server_id;
$strArr = array($server_id);
```

It didn't.